# How do you get LiveReload to work with Octopress using Guard

Tags: octopress

I am using this guide to add liveReload to Octopress.

http://www.erikzaadi.com/2012/09/16/using-live-reload-with-octopress/

Once I get to 'rake generate && rake watch',
The command line spits out I am missing a specific gem; i.e.'rake-0.9.6', which is strange because I thought by installing the bundle took care of that.

I suspect that bundle is being saved elsewhere; but shouldn't that bundle be saved in the directory of my choosing (i.e. Sites/myproject?)

Answer (score 1):

Add these two entries to your Gemfile, in the :development group:

`gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-livereload'`

Create a file called Guardfile containing something like:

`guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{public/generated})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
end`

Start 2 shell tabs running these commands: rake generate && rake watch and guard
`

> rake generate && rake watch
>   `

start guard LiveReload
`

> guard
>   `

*It’s neat to get LiveReload working with Octopress. However, the generation can finish after your page does a reload, so you won’t see your latest changes. I’ll update this blog post when I figure out a solution to that one. Until then, you may find it more convenient to manually refresh the blog page yourself.
It’s worth noting that if you’re running any other instance of guard- LiveReload, then one of these two copies will win and one won’t work. If you run a rails server this way, then this can bite you. It took me a bit of time to figure out why guard wasn’t working.*

source
http://www.railsonmaui.com/blog/2013/04/27/octopress-setup-with-github-and-org-mode/#sec-4